# Make a physical stoplight react to Jenkins build

Tags: web-services, build, automation, raspberry-pi, hardware

I'm trying to create a simple program to have an actual stoplight show red or green based on whether or not my integration tests pass in Jenkins.

Red - No

Green - Yes

I realize this is very vague, but any sort of tutorial that hooks up any physical relay to a light from a raspberry pi that uses a web-hosted variable should be enough to get me going.

Answer (score 0):

I used this [API](http://wiringpi.com/) when I did mine.

Mine was super simple/simplistic. I was able to write a bash script using this API [GPIO](http://wiringpi.com/the-gpio-utility/) cli stuff. It just turns the [pin on](https://github.com/scirelli/pi_gpio_ac_switch_controller/blob/master/on.sh) or off, so I have a script to turn the pin on and one to turn a pin off.

I used a web server and ran them as CGI scripts. So essentially the Rpi runs a web server, you hit a page that runs the on bash script. You hit another page that runs the bash off script.

Here's my [project on github](https://github.com/scirelli/pi_gpio_ac_switch_controller). It's a mix of my playing around and the actual code I used to get it to run.